Error: [render-resolver] "onLoad" filter is not a valid Go regular expression (on executing npm run dev)
I'm encountering an error when trying to build my project using esbuild. The error message is as follows:

Error: [render-resolver] "onLoad" filter is not a valid Go regular
expression:
"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\emails\vercel-invite-user.tsx"
Error: [render-resolver] "onLoad" filter is not a valid Go regular
expression:
"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\emails\vercel-invite-user.tsx"
at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1084:25
at responseCallbacks. (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:704:9)
at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:762:9)
at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CalanderManagementSystem\shedular\emailtrial\react-email-starter\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:680:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
at Socket.emit (node:domain:488:12)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:559:12)
at readableAddChunkPushByteMode (node:internal/streams/readable:510:3)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:390:5)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17)
The issue appears to be related to an invalid Go regular expression in
the onLoad filter.
Ensured all dependencies are up-to-date. Checked the esbuild
documentation for onLoad filter usage.

Despite these efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have suggestions on how to fix this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All I know is that the error says :
"onLoad" filter is not a valid Go regular expression:, so maybe you can't use it, or if you can how its being called isn't working correctly.
